# Find emails sent to a specific data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

Is there a way in marketing cloud to find what emails were sent to some select DE's? Even if it has to be checked one DE by DE, is there a way? Views doesn't give this info at DE level.
This will help to archive some of the DE's that is not being actively used. Thanks!

Comment: have you looked into Intelligence reporting for this use case?

Comment: yes I tried but not sure if there is only limited options for the instance. If you can share any lead , i shall check again. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The way I know is putting system personalization strings into email and then create a sendlog DE to capture those information. Hence you will have information both Email Name and the Data Source were used for the send.

Specifically, in the email based template you put a code snippet something like this

```
%%[
set @EmailName = AttributeValue("emailname_")
set @DataSource = AttributeValue("_DataSourceName")
]%%
```

And then you create the Sendlog DE, just make sure you create 2 additional fields in this DE call EmailName and DataSource.

Every send now will capture email name and DE name in the sendlog DE where you can find out which email names were used for a specific DE name.

Note: this way won't work in journey builder send, the data source name will show "All Subscribers" instead of the name of the DE.

Comment: Thanks Duc Le, will be a good solution going forward. I wish there is a way to get this info for existing sends as we need to consolidate the DE's.

Comment: @PJJD just a one note that you should set the data retention for the sendlog DE otherwise it will accumulate with large data since it captures every send

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get this info that I can think of would be to go to Email Studio > Tracking and go through each send one by one and check which DE was used under tracking details:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but there are multiple DE's for which the check is required, and it would be time consuming. no option if there is no other way. wish there was a report